# Jetpack Compose and Wireless Direct

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, android-wireless, android-jetpack-compose-tv

I know this is way too general, but I have a reason. I am looking forward to make a simple app that can transfer strings from my mobile device to my TV. I wish to transfer this data over Wi-Fi, provided that the TV and my phone are on the same network. Now, the Android Documentation for the `P2P` Wireless APIs is DEAD. It even uses some **deprecated** implementations, and to worsen that up, nobody cared to provide an up to date documentation for carrying it out in modern day programming.

All I want, is a reference to a reliable source that might be helpful in understanding this. I added the compose tag, again, so that the info is conveyed that the app is built using a declarative paradigm, unlike the traditional android system. The sources may still be using the old android system (I, however, would prefer a Compose app). If nothing, at least point me to the correct (and updated) documentation, if it at all exists.

Comment: This seems to have little to do with Jetpack Compose. Rather than focusing on that, you might want to explain in software development terms what "transfer strings from my mobile device to my TV" means. Do you mean that you are creating an app for some TV platform (Android TV, Fire TV, etc.), and you want your phone app and your TV app to exchange data?

Comment: Yes, exactly. It is an Android TV app, and it allows data exchange with a mobile, which makes it kinda obvious that I would also need a Mobile-Side app, or maybe configure the same app to run both on the TV and the Mobile and handle data-transfer based on the Device